# Efficient way to derive coefficient from (1+t) to t

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

Suppose I have the coefficient $b_i$ of degree $d$ polynomial defined on variable $1+t$.

Can i get coefficient $c_i$ that defined on variable $t$ in linear time ?

Namely,

$$
\sum_{i=0}^d b_i(1+t)^i = \sum_{j=0}^d c_j t^j
$$.

Comment: The natural algorithm does about $d^2$ additions ($f_m=(t-1)^m=(t-1)f_{m-1}$ and $g_m=\sum_{i=0}^m b_i (t-1)^i = g_{m-1}+b_mf_m$ for $m\in 0 \ldots d$).

Comment: In characteristic $p$ it becomes $O(d^{1+\log_2(p)})$